# Veterans Day Memorial in the U.S

Tags: visible-light, orbital-motion, solar-system

For the ones who know about it:

**How many more times will the Veterans Day Memorial stones' holes "align" perfectly?**

Some info from [this site](http://www.onlineatanthem.com/anthem-veterans-memorial):

> At precisely 11:11 a.m. each Veterans Day (Nov. 11), the sun's rays pass through the ellipses of the five Armed Services pillars to form a perfect solar spotlight over a mosaic of The Great Seal of the United States.

I know that there are probably several factors which could affect it (like tectonic motion or earth's orbit maybe), but if the designers hadn't been somewhat sure about its permanence, then I guess they wouldn't have used it for something of such importance to the U.S. So my question is essentially, for how long have they made sure that it works (from a physicist's standpoint)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in [the description of the engineering of the monument](http://www.onlineatanthem.com/news/memorial-science)

You can read the whole story at that link; I will just quote the most pertinent statement:

> Using the statistical mean of the 100-year data, the altitude and azimuth angles for the structure were adjusted to provide time/error fluctuation of plus or minus 12 time seconds from the International Atomic Time mark of 11:11:11 a.m. That small time difference allows for additional compensation of the variations that you mention. **We also checked the variance 500 years out, and if the structure is still standing, it will work.**

I added the **bold** in the quote above. So the answer to the exact question you posed is: "They made sure it works for 500 years" - but probably longer.

Incidentally, you can check this yourself by putting numbers through the [NOAA online calculator](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/) to see how much the azimuth and elevation change from year to year. The answer is: very little.

Here is a snapshot of the calculation for yesterday:

[image]

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing... But thanks^^